# Is it best practice to hide API keys in .env file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to hide API keys gotten from GitHub API and from other APIs. I found out that it is possible to hide keys in .env files and get access to those keys by using REACT_APP and ensure that .env file is added into .gitignore file in order not to be submitted to a server. `The question is Is it considered best practice the way of hiding keys I described above. Secondly, is .env file added to a server even if we add .env file into .gitignore file.

Comment: Show your .gitignore and the directory structure.

Comment: @MarkusZeller — Why? That's not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, hi Markus, from your experience is it right to hide keys in .env file and use them with process.env in application?

Comment: @Quentin `Secondly, is .env file added to a server even if we add .env file into .gitignore file.` tells me, he is doing something wrong.

Comment: @MarkusZeller — I think that's a question, not a statement of a problem.

Comment: @Quentin This is describing a problem: Adding a file to .gitignore which is still in added the repo. To solve this, I do need some more info.

Comment: @Dickens I am used to .gitignore let's say the `config.php` and instead publish a `config.sample.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be passing the contents of the environment data file to React, which is client-side code, then it isn't likely to be very useful for keeping things secret.

Mostly this will be useful for keeping your various environments separate (e.g. so you don't accidentally use the URL for your test API server in the production deployment of your app).

If you were using this for server-side code, then it would be useful to keep your secrets secret and not publishing them in a git repository (that you might want to allow other people access to).

Whether or not the environment data file would be deployed to your server would depend on your deployment process. If your deployment process consisted of nothing more than checking out your git repository to the live server, then no, it wouldn't be deployed.

Comment: sir, from your experience how would you hide API keys in your were in my position. I am just newbie in React and really want to know how it is right to hide API keys. Thank you:)

Comment: It would depend entirely on who I wanted to hide the keys from.

Comment: from bad people trying to steal the info like API keys:)

Comment: That's a given. It would depend on what level of access you expected them to have to your systems. Do they have access to Github? To the server? To the deployed app?

Comment: well, they can have access to the deployed app by registering and then logging in for example??

Comment: all in all, is it like fragile to keep keys and other secret data in .env file to access them with process.env?

Comment: Then you can't access the API directly from your client-side code at all.

Comment: No, it isn't fragile.